# discord.js check if user has permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want a command that can only be used by people who have the ban permission
current code:

```
if(msg.member.guild.me.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS'))
    {
      msg.channel.send("hi")
    } else {
      msg.channel.send("You do not have permission to use this command")
    }
```

I get the error:
msg.member.guild.me.hasPermission is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`msg.member.guild.me` is of type GuildMember and according to this
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissionsIn GuildMember has no method called `hasPermission`. Pay attention that a lot of discord guides you see on the internet are based on the old versions.

Comment: do you know what i do need to do for it work?

Comment: `msg.member.guild.me.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)` might work. check out this link  https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has

Comment: That will not work as it checks if the client has the `BAN_MEMBERS` permissions. `.me` is the client not the member

Answer (score 0):

`msg.member.guild.me.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')` looks to see if the client (bot) has the `BAN_MEMBERS` permission (back in old Discord versions anyways now it does nothing because `.hasPermission` has been replaced with `permissions.has`)

Use this [link](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) for reference to new permissions setup.

You need to check if the message sender has permission by using this code

```js
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js'); // add this to the very top of your file

if (msg.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS))
    {
      msg.channel.send("hi")
    } else {
      msg.channel.send("You do not have permission to use this command")
    }
```